# Too many fields bad for elasticsearch index?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

Let say I have a thousand keys, and I would want to store the associated values. The intuitive approach seems to be something like

```
{
   "key1":"someval",
   "key2":"someotherval",
    ...
}
```

Is this a bad design pattern for elasticsearch index to have thousands of keys? Would each keys introduced this way create overhead for every documents under the index?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you know there is an upper limit to the number of keys you'll have, a few thousand fields is not a problem.

The problem is when you have an unbounded set of keys, e.g. when the key is derived from a value, as you'll have a continuously growing mapping and thus also cluster state. It can also lead to quirky searches.

This is a common enough question/issue that I dedicated a section to it in my article on [Troubleshooting Elasticsearch searches, for Beginners](https://www.found.no/foundation/beginner-troubleshooting/#keyvalue-woes).

In short, thousands of fields is no problem - not having control of the mapping is.

Comment: Apart from the growing mapping and cluster state you mentioned, I am worry about if there would be overhead for each document. What I means is take for example, I may have a key that is only relevant to less than 10 documents, but say there is a million documents in the index. Would the other documents that don't use that key ends up having some empty fields/references (like in mysql when you have too many column with null value)?

Comment: The way the inverted index works, that's not a problem. Essentially, a term is sort of "prefixed" with its field in the dictionary. Here's a bit more: https://www.found.no/foundation/elasticsearch-from-the-bottom-up/

Comment: But what means "you don't control the mapping" ? If I am getting keys I do not know in advance, but I know that there will be no more then 10000 or 100000 different keys, why is it bad? What exactly happens when a new field is added to mapping this way?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch is not ideal for 1000s of key-value pattern in a document. and if you want to update them in real-time or something, then try redis or riak for that.

If you have thousands of keys in a document/record, essentially they become fields and the value become the text and indexed.

From information-retrieval perspective with large data, it is advised to use fewer big fields than numerous small fields, for faster search performance.