# Avoid mapping multiple fields in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I have the following problem when indexing documents in elasticsearch, my documents contain some fields that are not repeated in other documents, so I end having a mapping of more than 100.000 elements. Let's see an example:

If I send something like this to an empty index:

```
{"example":{
    "a1":123,
    "a2":444,
    "a3":52566,
    "a4":7,
    .....
    "aN":11
    }
}
```

It will create the following mapping:

```
{"example" : {
          "properties" : {
               "a1" : {
                      "type" : "long"
                      },
                "a2" : {
                      "type" : "long"
                      },
                "a3" : {
                      "type" : "long"
                      },
                "a4" : {
                      "type" : "long"
                      },
                .....
                "aN" : {
                      "type" : "long"
                      }
                }
        }
}
```

Then if I send another document:

```
{"example":{
    "b1":123,
    "b2":444,
    "b3":52566,
    "b4":7,
    .....
    "bN":11
    }
}
```

It will create a mapping double as the one above.
The object is more complex than this, but the situation that I'm having now is that the mapping is that big that is killing the server. 
How can I address this? is the multifield working in this scenario? I tried in several ways but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

Comment: For starters, my first feeling is that if two documents don't have the same keys (or a large subset thereof in common), they don't belong to the same type (i.e. `example`) in the first place. You might also want to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911162/too-many-fields-bad-for-elasticsearch-index). As Alex Brasetvik said, the problem is not to have too many fields, but to not be in control of your mapping and let it grow unbounded, maybe there is some thinking to do on your mapping.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty tough to give you a definitive answer given we have no idea of your usecase, but my initial guess is that if you have a mapping of thousands of fields that have no logical bond you've probably made some wrong choices about the architecture of your data. Could you tell us why you need to have thousands of fields that have different names for a single document type ? As it is there's not much we can do to pinpoint you into the right direction.

Comment: Well maybe you are right, the problem could be in the data architecture, we are using this architecture for a O(1) lookup in the code but we could serialize in another way. The usecase anyway imagine that example is a person and inside we have some attributes that define this person, something like "isTall": "yes", "goesToGym": "mondays", ... and like this thousands.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do so, create mapping as on example below:

```
POST /index_name/_mapping/type_name
{
    "type_name": {
        "enabled": false
    }
}
```

It will give required behavior. elasticsearch will stop to create mapping for fields, as well as parsing and indexing of your documents.

See these links to get more information:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-dynamic-mapping.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-object-type.html#_enabled_3