# ElasticSearch mapping for dynamic fields

Tags: database, elasticsearch, search, mapping

I have an index with the name 'dev-steps',

mapping for this index:

```
    {
        "dev-steps": {
          "mappings": {
            "steps": {
              "properties": {
                "cId": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                      "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "data": {
                  "properties": {
                    "ui034": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "ksms5": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "ui0tg": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "vcw5d": {
                        "type": "long"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "uId": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                      "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

I see a problem, any time when I add new value to the field 'data', that add a new property to the mapping; how I can create a dynamic mapping?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a **dynamic template** to your index mapping (Elasticsearch Reference: [Dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html)).

Comment: Hello, That's not a solution for me after add dynamic template I still see all list dynamic fields in the 'properties' key. I saw the same question in elastic forum https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-map-fields-with-dynamic-keys/76284/3
But maybe after 2 years elastic has some new feature for hiding all properties?

Comment: Could you please reword your question? It seems that I misunderstood your question and actually I'm no longer sure at all what your question is. Properties list all the fields in your mappings. Is it that you don't want new fields to get added to the mappings? This is also something that can be configured...

Comment: Sure, the better, if I will get in my mapping, something like this

"data": {
                  "properties": {
                    [dynamic_name]: {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                  }
                },

Because in feature I will have so many dynamic keys in my 'data' object

Comment: Ok, I think I understood: the classical "too many fields" preventing approach. And you found the proper solution approach to that.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking I found an answer to my question
[Too many fields bad for elasticsearch index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911162/too-many-fields-bad-for-elasticsearch-index)

and sure I found in elasticsearch docs
https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-beginner-troubleshooting#keyvalue-woes